# Criteria for a prime degree field extension to be Galois

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, not algebraically closed,
and let $k \subset L$ be a field extension of prime degree $p \geq 3$.

> I am looking for an additional condition which guarantees that $k \subset L$ is Galois.

An example for an answer: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118106/how-to-show-that-a-prime-degree-separable-field-extension-containing-a-nontrivia) is a nice condition, which says that if $L=k(a)=k(b)$, with $a \neq b \in L$ both having the same minimal polynomial over $k$, then $k \subset L$ is Galois.
(Of course, by the primitive element theorem, there exist $a \neq b \in L$ such that $L=k(a)=k(b)$; the point is that they are conjugate).

(See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893926/a-separable-field-extension-of-degree-a-product-of-two-primes?rq=1) question that asks for a generalization for degree product of two primes).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you expect another condition ? Thisone is necessary and sufficient. Equivalently you can say $|Aut(L/k)| > 1$

Comment: Thanks. So it is hopeless to find another condition? A one that does not involve explicitly conjugates or $Aut(L/k)$?

Comment: I meant if $\zeta_p \in k$ [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_theory#Kummer_extensions) $L/k$ is Galois of prime degree $p$ iff it is cyclic iff 
$L = k(\sqrt[p]{b})$ for some $b \in k$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Of course, as you have mentioned in a previous comment (now deleted), your above $b \in k-k^p$ (it is not the $b$ of my question).

Comment: Yes it is not the same, and finding it can be much more difficult than finding a primitive element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k(\alpha)/k$ a Galois extension of prime degree $[k(\alpha):k] = p$  and $char(k) \ne p$.

---

If $\zeta_p \not \in k$ then $k(\zeta_p)/k$ as well as $k(\alpha,\zeta_p)/k(\alpha)$ are Galois and (by looking at the possible automorphisms) $[k(\zeta_p):k]=[k(\alpha,\zeta_p):k(\alpha)] = n$ where $n \ |\ p-1$.

Thus $k(\zeta_p,\alpha)/k$ is Galois of degree $np$ and $k(\zeta_p,\alpha)/k(\zeta_p)$ is Galois **of degree $p$**,

by the Kummer theory it means $k(\alpha) = k(\sqrt[p]{a})$ for some $a \in k(\zeta_p)^* /(k(\zeta_p)^*)^p$

and hence $k(\alpha)/k$ wasn't Galois.

> Qed. $\zeta_p \in k$ and (Kummer theory) $k(\alpha) = k(\sqrt[p]{a})$ for some $a \in k^* /(k^*)^p$

Comment: Thanks! Please two questions: (1) $\zeta_p^p=1$? (2) What is exactly your additional condition?

Comment: @user237522 see the 1st and last line (if I didn't do any mistakes) this is a iff. Yes of course as usual $\zeta_p$ is a $p$-th primitive root of unity (which exists because the characteristic is not $p$)

Comment: Please, to be sure: Let $[k(\alpha):k]=p$, $p$ prime, $char(k)$ does not divide $p$. TFAE: (1) $k(\alpha)/k$ is Galois. (2) $\zeta_p \in k$ (apriori, $\zeta_p$ belongs to an algebraic closure of $k$).

Comment: @user237522 If $p$ prime $\ne char(k)$ then $L/k$, $[L:k] = p$ is Galois iff $L = k(\sqrt[p]{a}), a \in k^*, a \not \in (k^*)^p$ and $\zeta_p \in k$. Before you had (for $p \ge 3$) iff $L = k(\alpha) = k(\alpha_2)$ where $\alpha,\alpha_2$ are conjugates

Comment: In the special case $\mathbb{C} \subset k$, we necessarily have $\zeta_p \in k$?

Comment: @user237522 Where are you stuck about this ?

Comment: I just wanted to be sure I am not missing something, and looked for confirmation.

Comment: @user237522 I don't think so. If you want to be sure about something, read and check the proof.

Comment: @user237522 I made the same typo again, of course $\alpha$ doesn't have to be $\sqrt[p]{a}$ but they generate the same field..

Answer (score 2):

At this point of the discussion between the two users, 237522 and 1952009, the original question could be slightly "bent" and brought back to the following: "Given a field $k$ of characteristic  $\neq p$ (where $p$ is an odd prime), classify the Galois extensions of $k$ of degree $p$". Such an extension is cyclic of degree $p$ and will be called a $C_p$-extension, where $C_p$ denotes the cyclic group of order $p$. I extract from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2093431/300700 the following answer :

Denote by $G_k$ the absolute Galois group of $k$, so that any $C_p$-extension of $k$ is the fixed field of a subgroup of index $p$ of $G_k$, and any such subgroup is the kernel of a non trivial homomorphism $G_k \to C_p$, so that the $C_p$-extensions of $k$ are classified by the non trivial elements of the group $Hom(G_k, C_p)$. To progress further, introduce the field $K = k(\mu_p)$, where $\mu_p$ is the group of $p$-th roots of unity, and consider the restriction map $Hom(G_k, C_p) \to Hom(G_K, C_p)$. For any Galois module $X$, $\Delta=Gal(K/k)$ acts on $Hom (G_K , X)$ in the usual way, more precisely via  $(\delta, f) \in  \Delta \times Hom(G_K, X) \to f^{\delta}$ given by $f^{\delta}(x)= \delta (f(\delta^{-1}(x))$ for $x \in X$ . Note that this action is the only one which is functorial; here $\Delta$ acts trivially on $C_p$. Since $\Delta$ has order prime to $p$, it is classically known that $Hom(G_k, C_p)\cong Hom(G_K, C_p)^{\Delta}$, where the superscript $(.)^{\Delta}$ denotes the invariants under $\Delta$. Since $G_K$ acts trivially on $\mu_p$, one has $Hom(G_K, C_p)\cong Hom(G_K,\mu_p)$ as groups, but not as $\Delta$-modules because of the canonical action of $\Delta$ defined above. Actually, one can check easily that $Hom(G_K, C_p)\cong Hom(G_K,\mu_p)(-1)$, where $(.)(-1)$ denotes the so called "Tate twist", which means that the Galois action on $Hom(G_K,\mu_p)$ has been replaced by a new action defined by $\delta^{new} (f)= \kappa(\delta)^{-1}.\delta^{old}(f)$, where $\kappa$ is the mod $p$ character defined by $\delta(\zeta)=\zeta^{\kappa(\delta)}$ for $\zeta \in \mu_p$ . Consequently, $Hom(G_k, C_p)$ can be identied with the elements $f\in Hom(G_K,\mu_p)$ such that $\delta (f)=\kappa(\delta).f$ (these can be viewed as "eigenvectors" corresponding to the "eigenvalues" $\kappa(\delta)$). Now, by Kummer theory over $K$, $Hom(G_K,\mu_p)\cong (K^{*}/K^{*})^p$ , and this isomorphism is $\Delta$-equivariant, so we are done, at least theoretically.

Comment: About your last sentence, Kummer theory says any $p$-cyclic extension of $K = k(\zeta_p)$ is of the form $K(\sqrt[p]{a})$ with $a \in K^*/(K^*)^p$. And for such an extension $K(\sqrt[p]{a}), a \in K^*/(K^*)^p$ we get an homomorphism $\phi_a \in Hom(G_k,\mu_p),  \phi_a(\sigma)= \frac{\sigma(\sqrt[p]{a})}{\sqrt[p]{a}}$ the map $a \mapsto \phi_a$ being an isomorphism.

Comment: I wrote a short answer

Comment: Thank you very much both of you; I will carefully read your answers and see if I understand them. nguyen quang do, please, if you have an idea with $k$ of characteristic zero, it would be nice to hear about it.

Comment: $C_p$ is the cyclic group and $Hom(G_k,C_p)$ are one to one with  Galois extensions of degree $p$

Comment: @user237522  Sorry, my sentence char$ k $ prime to $p$ included the characteristic zero.

Comment: I erroneously read: "characteristic prime $p$" so I thought you meant characteristic $p$...

Comment: OK, I'll edit that