# $a,b \in \bar{k}$, such that $k(a)=k(b)=k(ab)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $a, b \in \bar{k}$ ($\bar{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $k$) be two distinct elements, such that
$k(a)=k(b)$.

Notice that $k(a)=k(b)$ implies that the degree of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $k$, $d_a$, equals the degree of the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $k$, $d_b$; denote $d:=d_a=d_b$.

Further assume that $k(ab)=k(a)=k(b)$ (hence the degree of the minimal polynomial of $ab$ over $k$, $d_{ab}$, equals $d$).

> **(1)** Could one find a concrete example to the above situation with, for example, $k=\mathbb{Q}$?
>
> **(2)** Is there something 'interesting' to say about $ab$?

Same questions **(1)** and **(2)** for the following special cases:

> **(i)** $b=a-\lambda$, for some $\lambda \in k^{\times}$? Should it have 'easier/nicer' answers?
>
> **(ii)** $d$ is a prime number $\geq 3$? Also, should the extension be Galois? See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329213/criteria-for-a-prime-degree-field-extension-to-be-galois) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118106/how-to-show-that-a-prime-degree-separable-field-extension-containing-a-nontrivia?noredirect=1&lq=1) questions.

Notice that [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26832/degree-of-sum-of-algebraic-numbers/26859#26859) question is not relevant (at least not directly, but maybe something can be obtained from it), since it talks about relatively prime degrees and sum of elements, while here we talk about equal degrees (probably $d>1$) and product of elements.

Perhaps the primitive element theorem can help?

Thank you very much!

---

In short, I am asking: Assume that the product $ab$ of two distinct primitive elements $a,b \in L$ for the field extension $k \subseteq L$ (namely, $L=k(a)=k(b)$) is also a primitive element (namely, $L=k(ab)$), does this tell something interesting?

Comment: An example: over the rationals, $a=\sqrt2$, $b=1+\sqrt2$.

Comment: Nice example, thanks.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, please, do you have an example of $a \in L-k$ such that $L=k(a^n)$ for all $n \geq 1$? Your above example will not be relevant anymore, since for $n=2$, we have $\mathbb{Q}(a^2)=\mathbb{Q}(2)=\mathbb{Q} \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Well if $L=\Bbb Q(1+\sqrt2)$ then $L = \Bbb Q((1+\sqrt2)^n)$ for all $n \ge 1$ =)

Comment: @KennyLau, thank you. Do you think that such an extension must be Galois? Especially in case where the extension is of prime degree. Please also see another question of mine https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060715/a-finite-separable-field-extension-k-subsetneq-l-satisfying-for-every-n-ge?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I think these experiences should be enough to show you that you need to think way harder before you ask your questions

Comment: @KennyLau, I (almost) agree with you; I should have seen those examples myself, but still remains the question whether such an extension is Galois (or perhaps there is an easy example for such non-Galois extension, maybe involving $\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$?).

Comment: Let $p$ be an odd prime, let $k(a)$ be of degree $p$ over $k$, let $b=a+1$. Then $k(a)=k(b)=k(ab)$. Galois is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, for a prime degree extension, if we take $a,b \in L-k$ such that $ab \notin k$, then necessarily $k(ab)=L$ (since $k \subseteq L$ does not have intermediate fields, by considerations of degrees).